# WooCommerce wrong price for free product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a problem with the price for the **free** product. Everywhere it says "**Free**", but in cart, it shows price `1.00` and all sum are **+1**.

Here I check that the price is 0 in database:

```
    var_dump(get_post_meta($ID, '_regular_price')); //array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
    var_dump(get_post_meta($ID, '_sale_price')); // array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }
    var_dump(get_post_meta($ID, '_price')); // array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" }
```

But I noticed this when checked `var_dump($_product)` in my cart

```
["price"]=>
  object(WP_Error)#20247 (2) {
    ["errors"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Error"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(36) "Date is required - please select"
      }
    }
    ["error_data"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

I asume I it needs to set up something for the product in admin, but don't know exactly what.

Any ideas how I can handle that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The message ask you to set date for the sale price. 
This can happen when you set you set a reduct price, even if the price is the same as the regular.
Set the end date to 2099-01-01, to check if you have the error yet.